# How do you add a filter on a measure / rows without excluding other measures?

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to add a filter to my table. My table includes measures such as Spends, Installs, Network Installs. The filter is based on a calculation on a measure:

IF [Network Installs] > 0 then 'Network' else 'Other' END.

However, when I apply Network Installs on this filter, all the other measures - Spends and Installs - in the table disappear. My aim is to have a table that includes a filter that can filter the rows (but not exclude other measures and dimensions) based on the calculation above. Additionally, my table is dynamic (groupable by other dimensions). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please include a snapshot depicting the problem

Comment: And show a few rows of sample data to illustrate how your data set is structured